# Going from Cell Phone 1/8" stereo jack (in mono mode) to Behringer MPA40BT-PRO

Tags: audio, audio-interfaces

I have a Behringer MPA40BT-PRO portable PA system.  I want to play iRealPro on my cell phone and have the output go to the Behringer PA just mentioned.

```
CellPhone => 1/8" ??? Jack ====> 1/4" Male Jack ==> Behringer
```

When I do this I change my cell phone from stereo to mono mode, so the cell phone is only output mono.  (See [Samsung Galaxy S8: How to Switch Audio to Mono / Stereo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWz-hR972PY)).

After doing this; When using mono-output on a cellphone, **should I use a 1/8" Male Stereo Jack or a 1/8" mono jack?  Or does it matter?**

There are many questions asking about going from mono to stereo and visa-versa but none like mine.

Some I read are:

- [Mono vs Stereo connections](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/23016/mono-vs-stereo-connections)
- [How to get AUX send mono signal converted to stereo?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/32967/how-to-get-aux-send-mono-signal-converted-to-stereo?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, why bother?  This thing can take Bluetooth.  If you trust the D/A converters in your phone more and/or want to avoid Bluetooth compression artifacts or connection failure, use a stereo 3.5mm to 2×RCA cable to the AUX input of the PA and let the PA deal with conversion to mono.  That's better than having to remember switching to mono and having to worry about balanced/unbalanced connections and shorting out a channel or non-standard cables.